# How to specify lookup_field in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm going to use UpdateAPIView in django. When I completed the view and ran the server, the following error occurred.

```
Expected view updateViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

I wonder why I shouldn't designate lookup_field as pk in my code and what I can use instead of pk. Here is my code

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import arduino

class arduinoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta :
        model = arduino
        fields = ['name', 'temp', 'humi']
```

views.py

```
from .models import arduino
from .serializers import arduinoSerializers
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, UpdateAPIView

class arduinoViewSet (ViewSet) :
    serializer_class = arduinoSerializers
    
    def data (self, request) :
        queryset = arduino.objects.filter(name=self.request.user)
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        
class createViewSet (CreateAPIView) :
    serializer_class = arduinoSerializers

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        serializer.save(name=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset (self) :
        user = self.request.user
        return arduino.objects.filter(name=user)

    def dataReceive (self, request) :
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid() :
            perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class updateViewSet (UpdateAPIView) :
    serializer_class = arduinoSerializers
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def perform_update (self, serializer) :
        serializer.update(name=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset (self) :
        user = self.request.user
        return arduino.objects.filter(name=user)

    def dataReceive (self, request) :
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = arduinoSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid() :
            perform_update(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('api.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

api\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('data/', arduinoViewSet.as_view({'get' : 'data'})),
    path('create/', createViewSet.as_view()),
    path('update/', updateViewSet.as_view()),
]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the urls please?

Comment: I reuproaded !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update view doesn’t know which id(pk) to update. Try adding the pk in the update url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('update/<int:pk>/', updateViewSet.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was said that you need to call the URL with a primary key, so it should be

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('data/<int:pk>/', arduinoViewSet.as_view({'get' : 'data'})),
]
```

But honestly, I think pk can be any value as long as it is unique, but your error occurred in the first place because, since you didn't specify a field, Django will look for one named 'pk'.

Comment: thanks but it's not work yet :( browser repeats same error

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer fixes the problem you were having, since the title of your question has, more generally, to do with specifying a lookup field for an `UpdateView`, I wanted to go ahead and post this more general answer for anyone who might come across this question if they are trying to do a lookup based on something other than `pk`.

Looking at [CCBV docs for UpdateView.get_object()](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get_object), you can see that if `<int:pk>` is not in the url, then `UpdateView` looks for `slug_field` (with a default name of `slug` which you can see under Attributes on the above page).  Therefore, instead of `<int:pk>` in the url, you could put `<slug:slug>` in the url.  In this case the second `slug` in the `<slug:slug>` part of the declaration is the default url keyword used by `UpdateView` if looking up by a slug.  As an aside, if you name your slug keyword argument in your url declaration something like: `<slug:different_slug_name>`, then you would need to specify `slug_url_kwarg = different_slug_name` on the `UpdateView`.  Finally, if the [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) **on your model** is named something other than `slug` (again, the default as you can see in the Attributes on CCBV), then on the `UpdateView` you would need to specify `slug_field = model_slug_field_name`.